# Windows Phone 7 WebBrowserTask problem

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm trying to open this url using a WebBrowserTask in WP7, and it doesn't work (I get a custom error on our website), but when I type it in by hand, it works fine. Any ideas?

It also works perfectly fine in Google Chrome and IE7.

This is the url:

http://www.symfonee.com/Improv/addison/comedians/Bio.aspx?ShowDate=12/15/10&ShowTime=8:00p&Uid=54918a0d-1beb-4552-bdc8-2d474e3ea5ae

And this is my code:

```
string url = "http://www.symfonee.com/Improv/addison/comedians/Bio.aspx?ShowDate=12/15/10&ShowTime=8:00p&Uid=54918a0d-1beb-4552-bdc8-2d474e3ea5ae";

WebBrowserTask browser = new WebBrowserTask();
browser.URL = url;
browser.Show();
```

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

Without any of the solutions below, this code works fine:

```
WebBrowserTask browser = new WebBrowserTask();
browser.URL = "http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=Windows+Phone+7&aq=f";
browser.Show();
```

I don't understand what is different?

Comment: Well one big difference is that your URL has unescaped characters in the querystring and the youtube URL does not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a bug with the SDK. In URL that contains `&`, you need to escape it.

For example:

`... Uri.EscapeDataString("&") + "ShowTime=8:00p"`

Answer (score 3):

This is most likely because your query string parameters are not URL-encoded. Modern web browsers will attempt to compensate when you paste that into the address bar because it's hard to URL-encode in your head. But when you're using an API, you should really URL-encode those pieces yourself.

Use the [Uri.EscapeDataString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.escapedatastring%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) method to encode each part of the query string individually. For example.

```
string url = "http://www.symfonee.com/Improv/addison/comedians/Bio.aspx" +
    "?ShowDate=" + Uri.EscapeDataString("12/15/10") +
    "&ShowTime=" + Uri.EscapeDataString("8:00p") +
    "&Uid=" + Uri.EscapeDataString("54918a0d-1beb-4552-bdc8-2d474e3ea5ae");
```

Comment: You can just URL encode the entire URL - I've done this and it works fine, you can try either method if needed if this doesn't work

Comment: In this particular case that may be fine, but I find the above method much cleaner, particularly when not dealing with constant values which is probably the case in any real-world code. For example, if one of the values contains an & or ? then URL-encoding the entire URL will not work as expected.

Comment: I still think it has something to do with the fact that your URL contains unescaped characters. You can try running Fiddler to see what exactly is being sent to the web server when you put the URL in a browser vs what your application is sending.

Comment: You are right, I found out that the problem is the ampersand, but I haven't found a good way to escape it. When the Uri finds the ampersand, it doesn't send anything after it, so I end up with a chopped url

Comment: Actually I just did. It IS the EscapeDataString, but I must include the ampersand, I followed you example and didn't include the ampersand. So it didn't work =P. Please correct to accept your answer. Thank you =)

Answer (score 1):

The following code worked for me:

```
s = "www.. "; //url
s = Uri.EscapeUriString(s);
task.URL = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're URI needs to be escaped indeed. As simpler way I think is :

```
string url = "http://www.symfonee.com/Improv/addison/comedians/Bio.aspx?ShowDate=12/15/10&ShowTime=8:00p&Uid=54918a0d-1beb-4552-bdc8-2d474e3ea5ae";

WebBrowserTask browser = new WebBrowserTask();
browser.URL = Uri.EscapeUriString(url);
browser.Show();
```